# Howto design for extension

Tags: java, inheritance, class-design

There is a [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) rule [DesignForExtension](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#DesignForExtension). It says: if you have a public/protected method which is not abstract nor final nor empty it is not "designed for extension". Read the [description for this rule on the Checkstyle page](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#DesignForExtension) for the rationale.

Imagine this case. I have an abstract class which defines some fields and a validate method for those fields:

```
public abstract class Plant {
    private String roots;
    private String trunk;

    // setters go here

    protected void validate() {
        if (roots == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No roots!");
        if (trunk == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No trunk!");
    }

    public abstract void grow();
}
```

I have also a subclass of Plant:

```
public class Tree extends Plant {
    private List<String> leaves;

    // setters go here

    @Overrides
    protected void validate() {
        super.validate();
        if (leaves == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No leaves!");
    }

    public void grow() {
        validate();
        // grow process
    }
}
```

Following the Checkstyle rule the Plant.validate() method is not designed for extension. But how do I design for extension in this case?

Comment: You shouldn't throw an IllegalArgumentException in a method that takes no arguments...

Comment: @markt Let's pretend it's IllegalStateException for the sake of the "argument" :)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The rule is complaining because it is possible for a deriving (extending) class to completely replace the functionality you provided without telling you about it.  It's a strong indication that you haven't fully considered how the type might be extended.  What it wants you to do instead is something like this:

```
public abstract class Plant {
    private String roots;
    private String trunk;

    // setters go here

    private void validate() {
        if (roots == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No roots!");
        if (trunk == null) throw new IllegalArgumentException("No trunk!");
        validateEx();
    }

    protected void validateEx() { }

    public abstract void grow();
}
```

Note that now someone can still supply their own validation code, but they can't replace your pre-written code.  Depending on how you meant to use the `validate` method you could also make it public final instead.

Comment: I see the point, but I'm still missing a way to implement the validate() method "good" and "practical" at the same time. If Tree implements a final validateEx() and calls validate(), a class extending Tree (lets say Forest) will not be able to override validateEx().Solution?Implement validateExEx()?

Comment: Use a better name, then.  Maybe ValidateTreeEx().

Comment: Sure - they can't replace your code.. but how can validate() ever get called ?

Comment: Maybe - or even final public.  But if you'll notice, validate is called by the grow() function.  It's part of an internal operation of the class.

Comment: @markt, likely something _else_ would be instantiating a plant and `grow`ing it. That other thing, whatever it is, is part of the contract that must be followed when implementing a Plant. Side note: static analysis tools like Checkstyle and PMD are most helpful when implemented thoughtfully and intentionally.

Comment: I have used the proposed solution, but now I have bigger problem: empty non-abstract method (PMD rule violation), in abstract class. Is there any way to solve it?

Comment: I'm still confused as to how the implementing classes are aware that they MUST call the super validate() function as oppose to its own implementing validateEx() function. Is this just up to the developer to be aware?

Comment: @lux implemented classes don't call validate(). That function would be called by existing code in the application, whenever the object needs to be validated. This way, an implementing class can't replace or hide existing validation logic for the code in my answer: only extend it.

Comment: But what shall I do if I want to make inheritance deeper. For example: A extends Plant, B extends A and so on?

Answer (score 1):

Although the answer by Joel Coehoorn explains how to overcome the concrete problem posted by the OP, I’d like to suggest an approach which takes a broader view on ‘how to design for extension?’
As the OP points out in one of his comments, the given solution does not scale well with a growing (class) inheritance depth. Also, anticipating in the base class the need to validate possible child classes (`validateTreeEx()`) is problematic for obvious reasons.

Proposal: Check a plants properties at construction time and remove `validate()` altogether (along with possible setters; see also http://www.javaworld.com/article/2073723/core-java/why-getter-and-setter-methods-are-evil.html). The original code suggests that `validate()` is an invariant, which has to be true before each `grow()` operation. I doubt that this design is intentional. If there is no operation, which can ‘break’ a plant after construction, there is no need to re-check the validity over and over again.

Going even further, I’d question the soundness of the initial inheritance design. Without additional (possibly polymorphic) operations, `Tree` just reuses some properties of Plant. I hold the strong opinion, that class inheritance should not be used for code reuse. Josh Bloch has this to say (from Effective Java, 2nd Edition, chapter 4):

> If you use inheritance where composition is appropriate, you
>   needlessly expose implementation details. The resulting API ties you
>   to the original implementation, forever limiting the performance of
>   your class. More seriously, by exposing the internals you let the
>   client access them directly.

Also check out 'Item 17: Design and document for inheritance or else prohibit it' (also chapter 4 for the same book)

Comment: Thanks Horst, although your answer discusses the design of the sample code and not the original question: how to design for extension. It's really just sample code, not perfect probably.