# How to resolve method is not for extension check style error

Tags: java, eclipse, checkstyle

How to resolve this check style error

```
Method 'getUserDAO' is not designed for extension
```

in

```
public UserDAO getUserDAO() {
    return userDAO;
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Howto design for extension](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/662598/howto-design-for-extension)

Answer (score 1):

- Read the corresponding [documentation](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_design.html#DesignForExtension)
- Make the method final
- **or** make the class final
- **or** disable the corresponding check if you don't want to stick to that programming paradigm

Answer (score 1):

The tool is telling you that public methods should be final. That way a subclass won't be able to change how a class operates.

```
    public final UserDAO getUserDAO() {
        return userDAO;
    }
```